# How to Determine the Operating System (OS) for a Windows App (UWP / PC/Tablet 8.1 / Mobile 8.x)?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, operating-system

I have an app I created for Windows: PC/Tablet 8.1, Mobile/Phone 8.1 and UWP 10.

It is a WinRT app using C#.

To place an advertising banner in the app, it is required to make a separate ad unit ID for each operating system.

Is there a way to determine which operating system is currently being used?

It is possible to check which device is being used by using the code:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
isWindowsPhoneApp = true;
#else
isWindowsPhoneApp = false;
#endif
```

But how to know if the operating system is Windows 8.1 or Windows 10?

UPDATE:

I have come across an interesting article about getting the OS version for C#/XAML:

[Windows Store Apps: Get OS Version, beginners tutorials (C#-XAML)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Store-Apps-Get-OS-a5de724b)

It uses System.Type.GetType to check if Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsVersionInfo returns null.

I modified and tested the code, and it seems to work in the Visual Studio emulators and simulator.  I can't test for a Windows 8.1 computer since I'm using a Windows 10 computer, but for the Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile, it was accurate.  I haven't tested it on actual phone devices.

So it seems that checking for the type of AnalyticsVersionInfo that is only available in Windows 10 will return true or false depending on the OS.

So would the following code be recommended to use in a release version?

```
var analyticsVersionInfoType = Type.GetType("Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsVersionInfo, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
var isWindows10 = analyticsVersionInfoType != null;
displayTextBlock.Text = "Is Windows 10: " + isWindows10;
```

UPDATE:

One-liner:

```
var isWindows10 = Type.GetType("Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsVersionInfo, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime") != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, i found it at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("OSVersion: {0}", Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This .NET code does not work in my WinRT app.  Also, the very first remark on the page, labeled as "Important", says: "we do not recommend that you retrieve the value of this property to determine the operating system version", which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if a class that was only added in Windows 10 exists on the system.

```
[DllImport("API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL")]
private static extern int/* HRESULT */ RoGetActivationFactory([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.HString)]string typeName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid factoryIID, out IntPtr factory);

static bool IsWindows10()
{
    IntPtr factory;
    var IID_IActivationFactory = new Guid(0x00000035, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46);
    var hr = RoGetActivationFactory("Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionSession", IID_IActivationFactory, out factory);
    if (hr < 0)
        return false;

    Marshal.Release(factory);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That seems somewhat risky and complicated.  Is there no simpler way?

Comment: Why is it risky? You're just checking if certain type activation factory is present on the system. Your Type.GetType() approach way more work for the same end result. And this is much faster too.

Comment: How about a one-liner?

var isWindows10 = Type.GetType("Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsVersionInfo, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime") != null ? true : false;

It saves about a dozen lines of code and doesn't need to import a file or run an activation factory.

I'm still not sure though if this could actually be a valid solution for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
{
    case PlatformID.Unix:
    //do android stuff
    break;

    case PlatformID.MacOSX:
    //do apple stuff
    break;

    case PlatformID.Win32NT:
    //do windows NT stuff
    break;

    case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
    //do windows 95 and 98 stuff
    break;
}
```